# How to get Facebook friends in android after Facebook F8

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Looking for facebook friends

In our android app we are giving facility log in with facebook and we need to fetch all friends of logged in user so we can match their Id's and show common friends of facebook and our app also if they are not available on our app will show Invite/share button

We tried 'taggable friends' api but we are getting encrypted ids of friends so its not possible to match id's ... With 'Friends' api we getting only common friends which are already on our app but what about other friends ?

Please help us on this..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we need to fetch all friends of logged in user

That´s not possible since v2.0 of the Graph API, only for inviting and tagging. Those possibilities got removed too. There is no way to get all friends anymore, only those who authorized your App.

Comment: So, those who authorized the app, can we get email address of those friends?

Comment: only if the authorized the app with the email permission